# Unity fluent registration - can this be any shorter?

Tags: unity-container

If I have a class that takes in several constructor arguments including a string that can be null, I am currently using the following syntax for registering it:

```
    container.RegisterType<ISomething, Something>(
new InjectionConstructor(new InjectionParameter<string>(aString), typeof(ISomethingHelper), typeof(ISomethingManager)))
```

I added InjectionParameter to cope with the case of a null aString which Unity complained about without this.

Is all this necessary or can I shorten it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Nulls are a bit of a special case, since we can't derive a type from a constant of type null (it just comes through the compiler as type object). So short of writing a small helper function / class, yeah, that's as short as it gets.

I could see writing something like this:

```
public static class NullParam
{
    public InjectionParameter OfType<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        return new InjectionParameter<T>(null);
    }
}
```

Then you could write the above as:

```
container.RegisterType<ISomething, Something>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        NullParam.OfType<string>, typeof(ISomethingHelper), typeof(ISomethingManager)));
```

I'm not sure that's shorter enough to be worth the introduction of the helper.

The Unity API is designed around regularity and extensibility, not brevity or convenience. This does make some things wordier than would be ideal. The nice thing is that it's pretty easy to write little wrappers and helpers to make the registration code look the way you want it to.